# How do I detect when I return to the root view of NavigationStack in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationstack

How do I detect from the root view that I've returned back to the root view after navigating via NavigationLink to another view? .onAppear() is not triggering when I return back to the root view via the back button

Comment: Where are you using `.onAppear`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try one of these approaches:

1. using `.onAppear {...}` inside the `NavigationStack`,
2. using `.onChange(of: path) {...}`, outside of the `NavigationStack`

Working example code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            NavigationLink(value: "destination") {
                Text("go to destination")
            }
            .onAppear {
                print("----> onAppear ") // <--- here
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { _ in
                VStack {
                    Text("destination view")
                }
            }
        }
        .onChange(of: path) {
            if path.count == 0 {
                print("----> in root view ")  // <--- here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Moving the onAppear inside worked which makes total sense. Can't believe I missed this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

NavigationStack was introduced in SwiftUI with iOS 16. If you are working with lower version then this solution would work.

```
class NavigationTracker: ObservableObject {
    @Published var navigated: Bool = false
}

struct RootView: View {
    @StateObject var navigationTracker = NavigationTracker()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                NavigationLink("Go to Detail View", destination: DetailView(navigationTracker: navigationTracker))
                    .onChange(of: navigationTracker.navigated) { newValue in
                        if !newValue {
                            // Returned back to the root view
                            print("Back at Root View")
                        }
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var navigationTracker: NavigationTracker

    var body: some View {
        Text("Detail View")
            .onAppear {
                navigationTracker.navigated = true
            }
            .onDisappear {
                navigationTracker.navigated = false
            }
    }
}
```